# App crashes on iPhone 4s/5 but no other device

Tags: ios, core-plot

I just acquired new iPhones and installed the app I am working on onto them. The app is very unstable and crashes frequently. It does not have the problem on other devices. Here is the list of devices it has been built for and runs.

iPhone 3gs, iOS 4.3.1 works perfectly

iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1 and 6.1.2 works perfectly

iPhone 4s, iOS 6.1.2 crashes

iPhone 5, iOS 6.1.2 crashes

The main source of crashing seems to be Core-Plot when I plot a graph with many points.

Has anyone had this issue (and solution perhaps?)

Comment: Without complete error message and other clues about the crashes, there is no way anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue. The key is that the machines it fails on are dual core. I have a garbage collector running. So on a single core machine the collector was blocked. On dual core it ran on the the other core thus cleaning up the "so called garbage" graph.